# What conditions allow vectors $u$ and $v$ to be true in ${ℝ}^2$ and ${ℝ}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am having trouble understanding what this problem in my book is asking.

It says "Under what conditions is the following true for vectors $u$ and $v$ in ${ℝ}^2$ and ${ℝ}^3$"

and then it gives this equation
$||u+v|| = ||u|| + ||v||$

Can someone explain what conditions it is referring to or point me in the right direction?

Comment: It is not referring to any conditions, it is asking you for them! Do you see that it is generally not true that $\lVert u+v\rVert=\lVert u \rVert+\lVert v\rVert$? Take, for instance, $u=(1,0)$ and $v=(0,1)$. However, it is true when, say, $u=(1,0)$ and $v=(2,0)$. What makes the latter case special?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Thank you for clarifying that for me, I think I get it now

Comment: To reword it: suppose someone gives you two vectors $u,v$. Can you explain how to tell when the equation $||u+v||=||u||+||v||$ is true and when it is false? Your answer mustl have a format like this: "The equation $||u+v|| = ||u|| + ||v||$ is true if and only if [INSERT CONDITIONS HERE]".

Comment: Thanks for all the help, really clarified what exactly I was doing!